# TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration, with matplotlib.pyplot.legend()

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are several way to make a legend with matplotlib. May be the simpler way could be:

```
>>> line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label='Up')
>>> line_down, = plt.plot([3,2,1], label='Down')
>>> plt.legend()
<matplotlib.legend.Legend object at 0x7f527f10ca58>
>>> plt.show()
```

One other way could be:

```
>>> line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3])
>>> line_down, = plt.plot([3,2,1])
>>> plt.legend((line_up, line_down), ('Up', 'Down'))
<matplotlib.legend.Legend object at 0x7f527eea92e8>
>>> plt.show()
```

This last way seems to work only with objects supporting iteration:

```
>>> line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3])
>>> plt.legend((line_up), ('Up'))
/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py:137: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The "loc" positional argument to legend is deprecated. Please use the "loc" keyword instead.
  warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3519, in legend
    ret = gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 496, in legend
    in zip(self._get_legend_handles(handlers), labels)]
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

If I want use absolutely the second way with only one curve ... Hown can I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the reason for this is to define a one item tuple, you would use the syntax `(line_up,)`. Note the trailing comma.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.legend((line_up,), ('Up',))
plt.show()
```

You could also use a list if you would rather not include the trailing comma. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label='my graph')
plt.legend(handles=[line_up])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Oh great !!! Thanks a lot it is exactly what I looked for ! I'm ashamed that  I did not find by myself ... :-((